# html input pattern for dd.mm format

Tags: html, regex, date

I would like to have HTML input that takes date in "dd.mm" format (for example: 23.03, without a year). Can I achieve that with type="date" maybe?

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="dd.mm" required />
```

Is there any way, to write a pattern, that allows only numbers as input and decimal point prefilled at position 3?

Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: Apparently the answer is no but there is another way, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32149869/2386774).

Answer (score -1):

> you can try this example using jquery and you can get only date and month

Comment: Please include all the relevant parts of your answer in the answer itself (not in links). Also you seem to be using quote when you shouldn't be... please remove that too.